# Fully expanding $ref references in a json schema with Python

Tags: python, json, validation, schema, jsonschema

We have a fairly large and complex json schema with many includes via $ref references. Ideally using Python and jsonschema I'd like to take those schema and fully expand the references (recursively) to get the full schema.

Output in the form of a dict is fine (the standard data structure that jsonschema uses to represent a schema).

Comment: I don't think that it's possible to *fully expand* because $ref in json can have loops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the [json documentation](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.8).
You will find that circular $ref is not recommended but not prohibited.
So, in this case, it is not possible to *fully expand* all `$ref`

But if you sure that you do not have loops in your `$ref` I would recommend you to use [this repo](https://github.com/purukaushik/ref-resolver/blob/master/ref_resolver/ref_resolver.py) It has helped me in such situation. Code is really simple so you can change it on your own.

Answer (score 4):

I have tested and can also recommend the following module:

https://github.com/gazpachoking/jsonref

which is on PyPI. The [documentation](https://jsonref.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is good, has been very recently maintained (October 2018), and the syntax is such that it is a drop-in replacement for the standard json module:

from the home page:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> import jsonref

>>> # An example json document
>>> json_str = """{"real": [1, 2, 3, 4], "ref": {"$ref": "#/real"}}"""
>>> data = jsonref.loads(json_str)
>>> pprint(data)  # Reference is not evaluated until here
{'real': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'ref': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't an easy way to truly replace all the references into a native Python object (at least as far as I can tell). The `$ref`'s are replaced by `JsonRef` objects, which helps when running `pprint()`, but that's not good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that is capable of expanding refs in the current document, even for refs to external JSON schema files which themselves may referecne other JSON schema files.

Using `json.dumps()` instead of print enables the `JsonRef` objects to be fully expanded upon output.

```py
"""
Usage:
  json-schema-expand-refs.py <jsonfile>

Arguments:
  jsonfile   JSON schema file to have refs expanded

Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  --version     Show version.
"""

from docopt import docopt
from jsonref import replace_refs
from pathlib import Path
import json


def load_json(file):
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = docopt(__doc__, version="0.1.0")
    jsonfile = args["<jsonfile>"]

    # replace_refs returns a copy of the document with refs replaced by JsonRef
    # objects.  It will resolve refences to other JSON schema files
    doc = replace_refs(
        load_json(jsonfile),
        merge_props=True,
        base_uri=Path(jsonfile).absolute().as_uri(),
    )
    print(json.dumps(doc, indent=2))
```